# How do I prevent objects to be persisted from being serialized?

Tags: wicket

I apologize in advance, admittedly I lack understanding in Wicket.
I read that using LoadableDetachableModel will prevent the object from being serialized, but after running the test several times I could see that it still gets serialized (after session timeout or on page load after timeout, sometimes). I think maybe I am not using models correctly. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

the code looks like this:

```
    ...
    LoadableDetachableModel ldm = new LoadableDetachableModel<SomeSettings>() {
        @Override
        public SomeSettings load() {
            if (someSettingsDao == null) someSettingsDao = new SomeSettingsDao(); 

            return someSettingsDao.Retrieve("1") == null ? new SomeSettings()
                  : (SomeSettings) someSettingsDao.Retrieve("1");
        }
    };

    final Form<SomeSettings> form = new Form<SomeSettings>("someSettings", new CompoundPropertyModel<SomeSettings>(ldm)) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit() {
            if (someSettingsDao == null) someSettingsDao = new SomeSettingsDao();

            if (someSettingsDao.Retrieve("1") != null)
                someSettingsDao.Update(getModelObject());
            else
                someSettingsDao.Insert(getModelObject());

        setResponsePage(UserPanel.someSettingsPageProvider.getPageClass());
        }

    };
    ...
```

Is it my use of models? Or how the data is persisted?
Thanks.

Comment: As long as I remember, a LoadableDetachableModel is a lazy model. This is, the object won't be loaded until it is used. But I didn't know that it affected to object serialization

Comment: SoneSettingsDao is serialized. Does it hold any SomeSettings reference?

Comment: thanks to you both :) turns out it was another page that had the reference. (facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Data are persisted/serialized when Wicket decides to persist. After a component/page is rendered all components and models are detached. It means loadable detachable model detaches its inner model and there is nothing to be serialized. Of course serialization is made ever after page is rendered and it is not necessarry to keep it in memory.